# Laravel 5 redirecting back with post request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a page that is a POST route. This page has a delete button that routes to one more POST route , where I delete the specified database row and redirect back to the first page.

The problem is that when I use any of 'back()' or 'redirect()' functions it seems that they are producing a GET request to the previous URL. But the previous page is a POST only page.

How can I redirect back with a POST request and POST data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect()->back()->withInput();` to redirect back with all POST data.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects and https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects